# Android Parse query for data from more than two tables

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using Parse for one of my android application and struggling for a query to get output.

Application Parse DB has three table which is as described below-

> **User:** user related information with unique object Id
>
> **Post:** Contains Post related information with unique object Id and UserId(Pointer to user table) who create the post
>
> **Like:** UserId(Pointer to user table) represent who is Liking the post, PostId(Pointer to post table) which post is liking and unique
>   object Id

Now I want to make a single compound query for *All post for a specific user along-with total number of likes to corresponding post*. Please suggest a solution/query for that

Comment: If my answer was helpful you might want to mark it as the solution so the question is shown as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user creates a post, assign the user objectID to some post identifier property in the post table.

To retrieve all posts from a user, a query like this may help:

`query.whereEqualTo("objectID", currentUser.objectID)`

If you're just concerned about the like count, rather than each user who has liked the post, you may want to have an Integer value in the post table that is incremented after a user presses the like button on that post.

Comment: By adding a simple like count to the post table, that integer will be retrieved by the query. If your app is similar to instagram, maybe you can have a button that shows all users that have liked this post, where you perform a query on your Like table.

Comment: I also required to keep track of user who were liking the post

Comment: Hm. Okay. There are a couple of potential routes. One being you could store your postID in your Like table, and retrieve them with a second query  similar to `query.whereEqualTo("objectID", currentUser.objectID)` Second you could store an array object inside of your Post table. Lastly, which I believe would be the best, is to broaden your Tables. Of those three tables you could probably condense them to just two (User & SocialAction). Have some sort of enum or string to identify an action and then create a record for posts, comments, likes, shares etc. Would any of those be a viable solution?

Comment: For a combined SocialAction table a query might look something like `query.whereEqualTo("ActionType", "like").whereEqualTo("postID", currentPost.objectID)`

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own webHook.
Following this exemples here you can easily learn and develop your own stuff, you can even add some triggers to your application!

https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-cloud-functions
https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-beforesave-triggers

Answer (score 0):

### If User table doesn't have Post<.Relation> column

I suggest you to read about how to join queries.
f.g. make a query1 to get the user, then another query2 to get all posts with whereMatchesQuery('UserColumnInPostTable', query1) function.
Now, you are going to get all posts of a specific user efficiently.

.

### If User table *have* Post<.Relation> column

this is the easiest way

Just get the user object and get the relation object, then get the query, and find in background